# Caret - Changing tuneGrid gives different results for same parameters

Tags: r, caret, boosting

I'm having an issue training a GBM model in caret. I'm quite new to all of this, but I'll try to explain things as best as possible, but please let me know if you need any further info.

My code looks as follows:

```
library (caret)

set.seed(44)

tr.control=trainControl(
  method="cv",
  number=10,
  classProbs=T,
  summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
)

tune.grid=expand.grid(
  .n.trees = c(50),
  .interaction.depth = c(11,12),
  .shrinkage = c(0.001),
  .n.minobsinnode = c(10)
)

set.seed(44)

GBMMod = train(
  x=train[,-which(colnames(train1)=="outcome")],
  y=train$outcome,
  method="gbm",
  trControl=tr.control,
  tuneGrid=tune.grid,
  verbose=T,
  metric="ROC"
)
```

This returns the following results:

```
interaction.depth  ROC        Sens  Spec  ROC SD      Sens SD  Spec SD
11                 0.9057818  1     0     0.04106306  0        0      
12                 0.9040852  1     0     0.04803282  0        0
```

If I then select only the best parameters for tuneGrid, i.e. interaction.depth = 11 as follows:

```
tune.grid=expand.grid(
  .n.trees = c(50),
  .interaction.depth = c(11),
  .shrinkage = c(0.001),
  .n.minobsinnode = c(10)
)
```

the model returns a different ROC value for these exact same tuning parameters:

```
ROC        Sens  Spec  ROC SD      Sens SD  Spec SD
0.9110501  1     0     0.03660759  0        0
```

I would have expected the ROC value to be exactly the same, as the tuning parameters are exactly the same. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you use parallel processing when you fit the model? This makes me think that the seeds were not set when `gbm` was called. If you ran sequentially, they _should_ be the same but not necessarily when using parallel processing. Look at the `seeds` argument in `trainControl`. Set those for the workers and see if there is still a discrepancy.

Comment: I don't believe that I am using parallel processing -  the code for the model fit is exactly as I've set it out above. I tried adding seeds to trainControl using an example you'd provided to someone else, but I still had the same discrepancy. Is there anything else I could be missing? Is this not reproducible on your side at all? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't actually provided your data, have you? I get an error if I try to run the code!